# Google protocol buffer, how to set field of custom type?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have proto file like this:

```
message Control {

    message KeyStatus {
        required bool keyUp = 1;
        required bool keyDown = 2;
        required bool keyLeft = 3;
        required bool keyRight = 4;
    }

    message MouseClick {
        required double x = 1;
        required double y = 2;
        optional bool buttonRight = 3;
    }

    required KeyStatus keyStatus = 1;
    required double angle = 2;
    optional MouseClick mouseClick = 3;
}
```

In generated code there is no method `set_keystatus` or `set_mouseclick`, only `set_angle`. How can I set keystatus then?

Comment: For now I have to use const_cast for get method, it solved a problem but it's not a good way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#fields)? Try, for example, the `mutable_keystatus()` method.